# Correct use of null-conditional operator in LINQ while reading XML

Tags: c#, linq, null-conditional-operator

I have following XML file that I am parsing using XML serializer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Projects>
    <Global>
        <Variables>
            <Variable name="GlobalVar1" value="GV1"/>
            <Variable name="GlobalVar2" value="GV2"/>
        </Variables>
    </Global>
    <Project>
        <Variables>
            <Variable name="LocalVar1" value="LV1"/>
            <Variable name="LocalVar2" value="LV2"/>
        </Variables>
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

I am building a dictionary of variables - name-value pairs. I wrote following LINQ statement which works fine (assume that I don't have duplicate variable names in global and project scope):

```
Dictionary<String, String> varDict = Projects.Global.Variables.Select(var => new { var.name, var.value })
                .Union(Projects.Project.Variables?.Select(var => new { var.name, var.value }))
                .ToDictionary(var => var.Key, var => var.value);
```

Now I have a twist - sometimes either the entire `<Global>` tag will be missing or it won't have the `<Variables>` tag. Likewise, sometimes `<Variables>` tag will be missing from the `<Project>` tag. For example: the XML file will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Projects>
    <Project>
        <Variables>
            <Variable name="LocalVar1" value="LV1"/>
            <Variable name="LocalVar2" value="LV2"/>
        </Variables>
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

I thought using `?.` operator (null-conditional), as follows, would help, but when `<Global>` tag is missing the following LINQ statement returns `null` (`varDict` is `null`):

```
Dictionary<String, String> varDict = Projects.Global?.Variables?.Select(var => new { var.name, var.value })
                .Union(Projects.Project.Variables?.Select(var => new { var.name, var.value }))
                .ToDictionary(var => var.Key, var => var.value);
```

What am I doing wrong or what is the solution?

Comment: I suspect there is a serious misunderstanding of how this works. Please show the code you are using to deserialize the XML.

Comment: You don't have `Global` anymore, you can think of `Global?` like `if(Global != null) ..do..`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?.` operator just avoids throwing a NullReferenceException. It still returns null.

```
// If Projects.Global is null:
var var1 = Projects.Global?.Variables; // Does not throw an exception, but var1 is null
var var2 = Projects.Global.Variables; // Blows up and throws a NullReferenceException
```

If you want the `.Union()` to work when the first part is null, it needs something to work off of. So something like should work (may need some tweaking):

```
var globalValues = Projects.Global?.Variables?.Select(var => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(var.name, var.value)) 
        ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

Dictionary<String, String> varDict = globalValues
        .Union(Projects.Project.Variables?.Select(var => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(var.name, var.value)))
        .ToDictionary(var => var.Key, var => var.Value);
```